# jQuery DateTimePicker set end date on change

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using jQuery DateTimePicker to set the start date in a text field in this format:

Aug 30, 2014 9:00 am

All I'm trying to do is set the end date to the same as start date on change event, only change the time to 4:00 pm

The following does all of that except I need 'am' to be 'pm'

```
<input type="text" class="datetimepicker hasDatepicker" name="eventStartDateTime">

<input type="text" class="datetimepicker hasDatepicker" name="eventEndDateTime">

var d = new Date();
d.setHours(4,00);

$("input[name='eventStartDateTime']").change(function() {
    $("input[name='eventEndDateTime']").val($(this).val());             
    $("input[name='eventEndDateTime']").timepicker('setTime', d);               
});
```

I feel like there's an easier and better way to try to do this.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To set the time to PM:

```
d.setHours(16);
```

since it uses a 24-hour clock.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
$("input[name='eventStartDateTime']").change(function() {
    var startTime = $(this).timepicker('getTime');
    startTime.setHours(16);
    $("input[name='eventEndDateTime']").timepicker('setTime', startTime);               
});
```